# Is there a size limit for HTTP response headers on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, http-headers

I was trying to run a profiler on some handler code up on appspot and was looking for a way to show the pstats output without writing directly to the response body (which is problematic for handlers responding with structured data such as JSON).

I decided to try writing the output to the response header, and added some js to my html-rendering handlers that could parse the header and `console.log()` it (turned out to be pretty simple and convenient to work with). For the non-html rendering handlers, I was thinking I might try and build a chrome extension to do something similar, but of course, whenever I'm making an ajax call to such a handler, the calling page (with the js to parse the header) can step in and handle the display.

All this looked good as I was testing on `dev_appserver`, but then I deployed to appspot and found that my custom header never showed up. I have similar pieces of code in this project that track the elapsed execution time of certain operations, and the custom headers I write that stuff to shows up fine.

I'm assuming there's a limit in place on appspot python runtime process that omits the header if it's greater than a certain length, but I don't see the size published anywhere on the developer site.

If there is in fact a limit, does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Perhaps this is a silly question but I'll ask anyway. Is the header being cached?

Comment: @bernie the custom headers I have showing execution times vary from request to request, so I don't believe cache is an issue here.

Comment: I see. Thanks for clarifying, and apologies for the off-base question.

Comment: What is the name of the header?

Comment: First, there are some headers you're not allowed to set: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#Responses
Second, at least for inbound headers, there is a limit of currently 16kb. That limit might also apply to the headers you send, but i haven't tested.

Comment: @TakashiMatsuo the header is called `X-Pstats`.

Comment: @T.Steinrücken I may run a test today where I emit various lengths to see if they stop showing up at a particular point, though I suspect 16kb might be it now that you point out the incoming limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I cannot find any documentation about this, but the limit seems to be 497 bytes for the entire header line (**including** the key, the colon, the whitespace after the colon, but **excluding** the `'\r\n'` at the end of the line).

Here's a Go test handler:

```
func Test(c appengine.Context, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    l, err := strconv.ParseInt(r.URL.Query().Get("len"), 10, 64)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }
    value := ""
    for l != 0 {
        value += "X"
        l--
    }
    w.Header().Set("Set-Cookie", value)
    w.Header().Set("Test-Header", value)
    w.Header().Set("Very-Very-Long-Test-Header", value)
    w.Header().Set(value, "Test-Value")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
}
```

Setting the `len` query parameter to 469 is the largest value that does not remove the `Very-Very-Long-Test-Header` header. 484 is the largest that will keep the `Test-Header` header, and 485 is the largest that will keep the `Xxxxx…` header.

They all add up to 497 per line, or if you will, 495 excluding the `": "`.

**NOTE** that this limit does not apply to incoming (request) headers.

**UPDATE:** The `Set-Cookie` header has a different limit: 4108 bytes instead of 497.

Comment: This was incredibly helpful Atilla. We were really baffled as to why our headers disappeared in production. Now we're just using the Set-Cookie header in lieu of our old x-jwt header for authentication.