# urlfetch is not sending long headers

Tags: python, google-app-engine, urlfetch

I'm trying to fetch a url using `urlfetch` on Google App Engine. For some reason, some of the headers are not sent when their value is too long. This only happens on production server (works on my dev machine).

Does this behavior makes sense? Is it documented anywhere? Is there a way to bypass this?

**Update:**
Found [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5409#c12) from 2011 that says there's an undocumented limit of 481 bytes for the header.

My code:

```
headers = {
    'LongHeader' : 'LONG_BASE64_VALUE' # 1172 chars
    'ShortHeader' : 'SHORT_VALUE' # 119 chars
}

response = urlfetch.fetch(
    url = url,
    method = urlfetch.GET,
    headers = headers)

# ShortHeader is received by the target server, but LongHeader is not.
```

Comment: Which headers are you trying to set?

Comment: @AndreiVolgin Just my own custom headers, not one of the headers that cannot be modified. Also the same header is sent when the value is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that there are a non documented size limit of about 497 characters for the header size (including the key, color, space after colon and value).

There are open issues on the GAE repository:

https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10210
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=5409

And another SO question:
[Is there a size limit for HTTP response headers on Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15280027/is-there-a-size-limit-for-http-response-headers-on-google-app-engine)